# BTRFS and disk usage mystery

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, disk-space, btrfs

```
# df -h /
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2               119G  113G  5.5G  96% /
```

and BTRFS agrees:

```
# btrfs fi df /
Data, single: total=111.00GiB, used=110.53GiB
System, single: total=32.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=3.00GiB, used=1.69GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=364.03MiB, used=0.00B
```

```
# du -shcx /
62G     /
62G     total
```

and BTRFS agrees:

```
# btrfs fi du / -s
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
  59.44GiB    58.17GiB     1.28GiB  /
```

`btrfs balance start /` ran for 2 hours but brought no change and there are no subvolumes in the system either:

```
# btrfs subvolume list /
#
```

**so where is half of my disk?** some more info:

```
# btrfs fi usage /
Overall:
    Device size:                 118.99GiB
    Device allocated:            114.03GiB
    Device unallocated:            4.96GiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                        112.21GiB
    Free (estimated):              5.44GiB      (min: 5.44GiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.00
    Metadata ratio:                   1.00
    Global reserve:              363.31MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,single: Size:111.00GiB, Used:110.52GiB
   /dev/sda2                     111.00GiB

Metadata,single: Size:3.00GiB, Used:1.69GiB
   /dev/sda2                       3.00GiB

System,single: Size:32.00MiB, Used:16.00KiB
   /dev/sda2                      32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sda2                       4.96GiB
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm facing a similar issue

Comment: Facing the exact same issue, did you find out ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of "dark file system matter" are *BTRFS snapshots*.

In my case, I was doing a system upgrade and apt had made three snapshots during that process, which took up half of my root disk!

You can check whether this is the case by running

```
sudo btrfs subvolume list -s /
```

which will list all snapshots under the root directory. If this shows that you have snapshots, you can get rid of them and free your disk space using

```
sudo apt-btrfs-snapshot delete-older-than 0d
sudo btrfs scrub start /
```

.